# Correct method of encrypting application data

Tags: java, android, encryption, password-encryption

Just a quick question about the use of encryption for app data.

Say you have a mobile app, this app needs to store some potentially sensitive data. In this case, a list of corporate ip addresses that need to be kept hidden.

The obvious answer would be to encrypt with the hash of a user's password. However in this case, a user account is optional and so a password may not exist. What would be the next best method of encrypting the stores data?

My first guess and probably the least secure is a key built into the application, but issue here is risk of different attacks that could see that password recovered.

Next guess would be finding some sort of identifier of the device that can be used as a seed for a password generator. Again seems like a flawed method.

Last idea is to securely randomly generate the password and store it encrypted with one of the above methods.

Am I following the right train of thought or am I way off?

I have a decent understanding of cryptography algorithms but finding the right application has me scratching my head. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/ might be a place to visit in case you dont get good answers here.

Comment: Many Android devices released in the last couple of years have hardware-back keystores where secret/private keys can be stored (and sometimes generated) in a trusted execution environment. The key material of such keys is not accessible to apps or even the OS. Though it's possible that another app that has managed to run as the same user as your app could _use_ your keys on the device where they reside, even if they can't extract the keys for use elsewhere.. I haven't looked into that.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is: as long as your data **only** resides on the mobile device, in the end, you are limited. In that sense: if you need to store information in a secure and reliable way, then you should consider a "server side" solution.

If that isn't possible, the next best thing is to have your app **ask** the user for a distinct password - which is then used as key as outlined in your question. You definitely do not want a **single** generic key that works for all users/devices.

But of course - asking the user to type a special password each time he wants to use the app will not be a solution your users will like. So you will have to *offer* the user to store that password somehow - which again increases the range of potential attacks.

Long story short: without a "remote" service you simply have to balance "user experience" with "enough security". Depending on your user set, you have to determine what is more crucial to these people - security or convenience.

Comment: He doesnt have to ask user to password everytime. He can make a remember me button at login page and if its clicked he can store users password to database and if he logs out, he can delete the password from database.

Comment: @YusufÇağlar You are correct - I was a bit too lazy here. Please see my updates.

Comment: This does seem to be where I would have to head. The issue is that there will have to be daemons running in the background that need to make use of the stored data. They either need to have access to this data or the data will have to be stored off the device and accessed remotely whether through a service or provided on request. And in that case, convenience will have to suffer with a required username and password though different keys could be used for different security levels. Daemon communication could use one key while data access might require a more secure key behind a master pass

Answer (score -1):

Next guess would be finding some sort of identifier of the device that can be used as a seed for a password generator. Again seems like a flawed.
--- ?

You can encrypt it with the hash of ANDROID_ID or UUID in place of password

What's your opinion on this?

Comment: Only reason I thought that is the ANDROID_IS or UUID is due to them being easily discoverable on the device. So if there was a rouge app hypothetically, it would simplify cracking the encrypted file. A salt would reduce that possibility but without careful programming, could be found through reverse engineering the application.

Could be wrong.
Maybe UUID used as an identifier of a remote key manager? But this starts getting a bit too complicated for the application.

Comment: Bad idea: using the android id means - as soon as anybody figures the mechanism, you know how to break *any* device out there.

Comment: I agree, which is why I thought using unique public identifiers was a bad idea. It seems there isn't much option outside of using a password and limiting security to a password keystore built into the device. Better yet use an online database with asymmetric encryption for proof of identity. That does add a lot of complexity to what should be a simple application data save feature.

Comment: Indeed as said by @GhostCat this would be a bad idea if anyone figures the mechanism